# Encoding/Decoding String

Tags: base64, encode, urlencode

I'm trying to figure out how exactly a string of numbers is being encoded.

The input is `2010115347` and the output is `vaqU0QjquH2q3ZQDYplthQ==`.

Another example:

Input is `2010322555`and output is `V4ofw4NbNx6FWPCSGUiEHw==`

Doesn't look like a typical Base64 encoding. Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What code is generating this?

Comment: @JasonCoco, I'm trying to figure that out. Is there a way of backtracking and figuring out the code that generated this?

Comment: The input is 80-bit long, the decoded output is 128-bit. It means that the input was transformed somehow to 128-bit before it got encoded. Now you need to figure out what the transformation was: 0x32303130313135333437 -> 0xBDAA94D108EAB87DAADD940362996D85 and 0x 32303130333232353535 -> 0x578A1FC3835B371E8558F0921948841F. Good luck :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this via Javascript - I have a feeling it is being done on the browser side...i.e. when I submit 2010115347, I get the encoded output

Comment: Yes, JS becomes more and more powerful and I've even seen a complete RSA stack implementation in JS. Here is yet another wild guess - it might be that somebody is implementing "key stretching" algo. Output is 128-bit, which is very popular, generated keys are random enough and differ a lot even though input strings are similar. Do you have more inputs with a different length?

Comment: If it's done in JS, you should be able to download it and check the code.

Comment: ... or it can be an encryption - both 64-bit and 128-bit block ciphers are valid suspects if this is the case.

Comment: All the inputs are the same length - 10 numbers.